# Uploadcare: How to prevent losing image quality?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, uploadcare

I have an image original with 700x500 and 50kb file size.

How to prevent losing its quality when using CDN `-/resize/800x/-/stretch/off/` api, if there is already a small file size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `/quality/best/` CDN URL modificator.

From [Uploadcare documentation](https://uploadcare.com/documentation/cdn/):

> **/quality/:mode/**
>
> Set quality of result image. If not specified, mode normal is used. In
>   most cases this is just fine. But if you prefer image quality over
>   page loading speed you can use `/quality/better/`. Has no effect on
>   non-jpeg images.

Mode can be `normal`, `better`, `best`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there is a `best` option.